# json serializaing list of objects cause having Object notation for each tuple

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, serialization

I need to have a json with this format:

```
var projects = [
        { Title: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix' },
        { Title: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta' },
        { Title: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler' },
        { Title: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle' }
    ];
```

in web method I serialized list of objects this way:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetUserProfileProjects()
    {
        List<Test> data = new List<Test>() {
            new Test{ Title= "Dave Jones", City= "Phoenix" },
            new Test{ Title= "Jamie Riley", City = "Atlanta" },
            new Test{ Title= "Heedy Wahlin", City= "Chandler" },
            new Test{ Title= "Thomas Winter", City= "Seattle" }
        };
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(data);
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

but the json result in ajax call is in this format:
[image: Json Result]

why each item is hooked to an Object ?

Comment: any reason you aren't using Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: no reason! U mean Newtonsoft.Json resolve the problem?

Comment: no it won't but Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET) is faster

Answer (score 1):

<s>You would want to serialize a `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>` to get the desired result.</s>

`Test` is an object, therefore, each entry is hooked up to that particular object.

As long as you continue to use `List<Test>` your JSON result will be the same.

Comment: So how can I deal with it?

Comment: @AsmaGheisari at first thought, i don't think you can get your collection to format like that.. maybe there's a JSON expert who can help, but i believe i technically answered your question lol